# CentOS yum update creates two kernels

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, virtualbox, yum

I ran `yum update` on CentOS. Reboot. I now have two OS images/kernels?

- /lib/modules contains two kernel directories. The old one, and the new, updated one.
- When I restart the OS it asks me to boot from either the old one or the new updated os version.

How can I `yum update` to replace the old OS, not just create a new kernel beside the old one. Do I just have to somehow delete the old version before updating to the new version?
I'm running CentOS on virtualbox. CentOS-6.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, wouldn't it be rude of your system to delete your last known working kernel before you know for sure the new kernel works for you?  You don't want that.

Once you decide you like your kernel, you can:

```
# package-cleanup --old-kernels --count=1
```

to reclaim the space.